Execute Task using Serial Executor
There is class which can be called from any thread.
class TicketSubmission {

    func submitTicket(ticketId: String) async {

    }
}

Note here TicketSubmission is not an actor. It will be a simple class.
This can be called from Different tasks.
let submission = TicketSubmission()


Task {

 submission.submitTicket(ticketId: "1")

}

Task {
 submission.submitTicket(ticketId: "2")
}

Task {
 submission.submitTicket(ticketId: "3")
}

How can this made in a way that these execute serially, i.e ticket id 1,2 and 3.
Instead of random ticket being processed serially.
There is a SerialExecutor protocol which can be subclassed. But I am not exactly sure how to use and make sure all of these execute on 1 single task.

Protocols are not "subclassed". They are adopted (and conformed to).

Do not be misled by the name: A SerialExecutor is designed to solve a very different problem, namely when you do not want an actor to use the cooperative thread pool. But it sounds like you simply want a series of tasks to run sequentially (with no actor-reentrancy).
I might recommend AsyncChannel from the swift-async-algorithms package. You would have a for-await-in loop monitor the channel, and then you can send ticket identifiers to that channel:
actor TicketService {
    private let channel = AsyncChannel<String>()

    func monitorChannel() async {
        for await ticketId in channel {
            await ticketHandler(ticketId: ticketId)
        }
    }

    func submitTicket(ticketId: String) async {
        await channel.send(ticketId)
    }
}

private extension TicketService {
    func ticketHandler(ticketId: String) async {
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
    }
}

And you would monitorChannel when the app starts, have submitTicket send ticket identifiers, and ticketHandler will process them one at a time. For example, in SwiftUI:
struct DetailView: View {
    let service = TicketService()
    @State var id = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Submit") {
                id += 1

                Task {
                    await service.submitTicket(ticketId: "\(id)")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            await service.monitorChannel()
        }
    }
}

Yielding:

So, you can follow what is going on in this timeline, the Ⓢ signposts are where I clicked the button to submit a new ticket, but you can see the ticketHandler lane in this “Points of Interest” graph will process them one at a time.
In this run, represented by the above “Points of Interest” timeline:

I clicked three times (faster than ticketHandler could run them) … demonstrating that it handles these sequentially while the UI remains responsive;
I waited until they finished, and clicked one more time … demonstrating that if there were no going, that this fourth ticket was handled immediately;
I then dismissed the view (canceling the monitoring of the channel) … demonstrating that you can cancel this channel, if that is desired;
I then re-entered the view in question and clicked 9 times in quick succession, but then canceled all of this before they finished … demonstrating cancelation of the channel in progress.


In the above code snippets, I omitted the Instruments’ “Points of Interest” instrumentation to avoid distracting you with code unrelated to your question at hand. But here is the complete MRE:
import os.log
import AsyncAlgorithms

let poi = OSSignposter(subsystem: "TicketService", category: .pointsOfInterest)

actor TicketService {
    private let channel = AsyncChannel<String>()

    func monitorChannel() async {
        let state = poi.beginInterval(#function, id: poi.makeSignpostID())
        defer { poi.endInterval(#function, state) }

        for await ticketId in channel {
            await ticketHandler(ticketId: ticketId)
        }
    }

    func submitTicket(ticketId: String) async {
        let state = poi.beginInterval(#function, id: poi.makeSignpostID(), "\(ticketId)")
        defer { poi.endInterval(#function, state, "\(ticketId)") }
        await channel.send(ticketId)
    }
}

private extension TicketService {
    func ticketHandler(ticketId: String) async {
        let state = poi.beginInterval(#function, id: poi.makeSignpostID(), "\(ticketId)")
        defer { poi.endInterval(#function, state, "\(ticketId)") }

        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
    }
}

And:
struct DetailView: View {
    let service = TicketService()
    @State var id = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Submit") {
                id += 1
                poi.emitEvent("Click", "\(id)")

                Task {
                    await service.submitTicket(ticketId: "\(id)")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            await service.monitorChannel()
        }
    }
}

I then profiled this with Instruments, selected the “Time Profiler” template, and then started the recording.

SerialExecutor is irrelevant, i.e. it does not serialize accesses in some special way.
If submitTicket has no await calls, then it will suffice to make your class an actor:
actor TicketSubmission {
    func submitTicket(ticketId: String) async {

    }
}

You say it is not an actor, but it will need to be one. — If submitTicket does have await calls, then you will have to supply further code to prevent submitTicket from being called while it is already suspended at an await point. This will boil down to a case identical to, e.g. the answer to the question Swift 5.5 Concurrency: how to serialize async Tasks to replace an OperationQueue with maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1?.
